# error Collecting pandas==1.3.0 in alpine image

Tags: python, airflow, alpine-linux, pipenv

I am trying to install apache-airflow inside a docker image with alpine, the docker file is the following:

```
FROM python:3.9.5-alpine3.13
WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* ./

RUN apk add --no-cache libressl-dev musl-dev libffi-dev libressl-dev musl-dev libffi-dev gcc build-base
RUN apk add gcc musl-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev python3-dev
RUN apk update && apk add libressl-dev postgresql-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev python3-dev 

RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile

RUN airflow db init
RUN airflow users create --username admin --password admin --firstname Anonymous --lastname Admin --role Admin --email admin@example.org
RUN cp dags ~/airflow/dags/
RUN airflow webserver
RUN airflow scheduler

COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./src/.env.docker ./src/.env

CMD ["python3", "src/main.py"]
```

But when I execute that I got the following error:

> An error occurred while installing cryptography==3.4.7; python_version >= '3.6' --hash=sha256:3d10de8116d25649631977cb37da6c

I tried solved installing another a lot of libraries but I still cannot install any idea?

**EDIT**

It is necessary to install rust in alpine, but that alpine has an old version.

**EDIT 2**

After update the docker file like this:

```
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine3.14
WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* ./

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo

RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile

RUN airflow db init
RUN airflow users create --username admin --password admin --firstname Anonymous --lastname Admin --role Admin --email admin@example.org
RUN cp dags ~/airflow/dags/
RUN airflow webserver
RUN airflow scheduler

COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./src/.env.docker ./src/.env

CMD ["python3", "src/main.py"]
```

I got the following error:

> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting pandas==1.3.0
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached pandas-1.3.0.tar.gz
> (4.7 MB) [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     ERROR: Command errored
> out with exit status 1: [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
> command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools,
> tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lfncf2u8/pandas_6f9f84af90264ff59c98fca45e89ed74/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lfncf2u8/pandas_6f9f84af90264ff59c98fca45e89ed74/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-s8ljky3j
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:          cwd:
> /tmp/pip-install-lfncf2u8/pandas_6f9f84af90264ff59c98fca45e89ed74/
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Complete output (7 lines):
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Traceback (most recent call
> last): [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File "", line
> 1, in  [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       File
> "/tmp/pip-install-lfncf2u8/pandas_6f9f84af90264ff59c98fca45e89ed74/setup.py",
> line 650, in  [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
> ext_modules=maybe_cythonize(extensions,
> compiler_directives=directives), [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
> File
> "/tmp/pip-install-lfncf2u8/pandas_6f9f84af90264ff59c98fca45e89ed74/setup.py",
> line 414, in maybe_cythonize [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
> raise RuntimeError("Cannot cythonize without Cython installed.")
> [pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     RuntimeError: Cannot cythonize
> without Cython installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Answer for main question

Do you try `python3 -m pip install cryptography==3.4.7` ?

## Answer for `EDIT 2`

You probably need to install [**Cython**](https://cython.org/).
I redirect you to this page about **Cython** in **Alpine**:

> https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/cython

You can also try to run `python3 -m pip install Cython`.